# How to use WordPress REST API v2 to search posts?

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, search

I am writing Android application and I am using WordPress REST API v2 for communication with WordPress from my Android application. I have implemented Activity that lists all posts from single category:

```
http://wordpress.dev/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=X
```

But now I am adding search box in my application where user can enter some text and now I need to use this text to perform search over all categories

I can use same endpoint but different parameters:

```
http://wordpress.dev/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?search=<SEARCH TEXT>
```

In my local wordpress database I have a lot of posts that are called "POST TITLE #XY" and one that is called "Cover Photo"

So if I execute this:

```
http://wordpress.dev/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?search=title,post
```

I get only those that has post and title in the title, however if I add one more word:

```
http://wordpress.dev/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?search=title,post,cover
```

I get zero posts...

How can I perform search and get posts that includes one or more keywords that I am sending in request?

Answer (score 9):

You can use [Search Results](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/search-results/) REST API  Endpoint to seach by keywords you provide.

For example `http://yourdomain.com/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/search?search=lorem&per_page=5&page=1` will search for the keyword `lorem` in your wordpress posts.

**Per_page** : limits the number of results per page

Comment: Thanks @daniel rubambura it was really helpful!

In my case I had to remove index.php from this URL above. So it's now like this:

http://yourdomain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/search?search=lorem&per_page=5&page=1

Answer (score 2):

I did something similar to what you are describing for a WP/bbPress android/ios app.  First, I made my own wordpress search api end point to hit. Then on the wordpress side I used a custom mysql query to query post titles and post content for the search string and return that to the api.

I made the query only return 25 results as I didn't need to have more results than that, with pagination and such.